# vuejs Treeselect display additional elements in the objective other than jd and label

Tags: vue.js

in my front end I use vuejs treeselect to display sever data. I would like to display additional info other than id and label while user click the select box. my array looks like this:

```
[ {"id":"1","label":"car", "price":"xyz", "desc":"sth sth sth"},
{"id":"2","label":"bike", "price":"aa", "desc":"blah blah blah"}
]
```

How can I display respective "price" and "desc" info while the user selected the label from the drop down. thanks!

Comment: Take a look to the documentation, it's pretty straightforward https://vue-treeselect.js.org/ and let me know if you have troubles to implement it

Comment: Thanks, ricardoorellana,
Does "Customize Option Label" session address this? I have tired to use slot option label but seems  I can't get the "node" object.  would you mind write a few sample lines as the example.  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `node.raw` to access option element in options array

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Treeselect: VueTreeselect.Treeselect,
  },
  data: {
    value: [],
    options: [ {"id":"1","label":"car", "price":"xyz", "desc":"sth sth sth"},
{"id":"2","label":"bike", "price":"aa", "desc":"blah blah blah"}
]
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@riophae/vue-treeselect@0.0.28/dist/vue-treeselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@riophae/vue-treeselect@0.0.28/dist/vue-treeselect.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Value: {{ value.map(item => item.desc) }}
  <treeselect
    :options="options"
    :multiple="true"
    v-model="value"
    value-format="object"
  />
  <label slot="option-label" slot-scope="{ node, shouldShowCount, count, labelClassName, countClassName }" :class="labelClassName">
     {{ node.label }} - Description: {{ node.raw.desc }}
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @ittus. Actually, that's not what I want. I think I can handle the optional display inside the treeselect dropdown. 

 As the example you provided above, what I want is once you click "car" the value display on the top  should show "sth sth sth" and while I select the "bike" the value should changed to "blah blah blah" . Any idea?  thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want the value of treeselect will be description, instead of id?

Comment: sorry, maybe I didn't state it clear.  Beyond the "id" and "label" , I have  other elements(such as description, price, Lot No. so and so...) in the array. what I want is once I select the label in the drop down.(in this example (car. bike). the respective description. price. lot No. ... also displays somewhere in the page. thanks!

Comment: In another word, I want to obtain node.raw data outside <treeselect> tag.

Comment: Updated, use value-format="object" as suggestion of @riophae on github

Comment: Thanks both. very close to what I want now. I think I will use a method to process `this.value` to get the values of the associate array in "value" object.  Is there a short cut directly bind those value to browser;I've tested `{{value.desc}}` or `{{node.raw.desc}}` none of them work.     @ittus, in the snippet above, can you display only the desc right after Value like `Value: sth sth sth`  without additional method in <script> . thanks!

Comment: You can use `{{ value.map(item => item.desc) }}`